# Pyramid using css clip path: line break

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a TODO list in a pyramid shape.
[This is what it looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIyLT.png)

How do I get the text to not go outside of the triangle?

```css
.todo-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.todo-item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <input name="todo" placeholder="TODO...">
    <input type="submit" value="Hinzufügen">
  </form>
  <div class="todo-list">
    <div class="todo-item">
      TODO Thing number 1 super important
    </div>
    <div class="todo-item">
      TODO Thing number 2 super very much important
    </div>
    <div class="todo-item"></div>
    <div class="todo-item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `shape-outside`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; /* we need an extra wrapper as a flex container */
}
.todo-list {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  width: 100%; /* don't forget this */
}
/* us shape outside in both pseudo element */
.todo-list i:before,
.todo-list i:after{
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0,100% 0,0 100%);
}
.todo-list i:after {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%);
}
/**/
.todo-item {
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="todo-list">
    <i></i> <!-- added this extra element  -->
    <div class="todo-item">
      TODO Thing number 1 super important
    </div>
    <div class="todo-item">
      TODO Thing number 2 super very much important
    </div>
    <div class="todo-item">
      TODO Thing number 3 super very much important
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `shape-outside` was where I got stuck, just couldn't get it to work with my layout https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/t9fs2p43/  Glad somebody figured it out!